# Plotly: Hide date in axis ticks but show in hoverlabel

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

In the axis ticklabels, I want to show only the month and the year (grouped), like this -

[image]

But that also means I have to sacrifice on the day of the date (1-31) in the hoverlabel. Is there a way I can hide the day part of the date on the axis (with grouped years and short month) and yet see it on the hoverlabel? Something like this but without the `01`s before each month on the axis.

[image]

You can recreate this graph by copying this code-

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='GOOG')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title=None, yaxis_title=None, xaxis_tickformat='%d%b\n%Y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very possible. You can start out with the following and fine-tune it from there:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{x|%d%b,%Y} value: %{y:.2f}")
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='GOOG')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title=None, yaxis_title=None)

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="%{x|%d%b,%Y} value: %{y:.2f}")
fig.show()
```